# Cloning the Git Repository on Eclipse (Transport Error)

Tags: git, github, ibm-cloud, devops

I am new in Bluemix services. I could not find an exact solution to this problem.

I have a web application on Bluemix and a Git repository on DevOps. I'm working on Eclipse (have Git and Bluemix plugins) and made some changes on the project. Now, I have the last version of the project in Local and Bluemix side and need to update the repository (which is still starter code).

As a first step, I am trying to clone the Git repository (on Eclipse). After I fill the URI and authentication fields, I am getting the error that is shown below. I can pass over SSL error by setting `http.sslVerify=false` but cannot solve the others. Thanks.

[image: Trasport Error]

**Error Log:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
 java.version=1.8.0_45
 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
 BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
 Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
 Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

 org.eclipse.egit.ui
 Error
 Thu Apr 23 12:46:33 EEST 2015
 https://hub.jazz.net/git/***/***: authentication not supported

 org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://hub.jazz.net/git/***/***: authentication not supported
     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
     at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
     at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:324)
     at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
 Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://hub.jazz.net/git/***/***: authentication not supported
     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:494)
     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:309)
     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:202)
     ... 4 more
```

**NOTE:** After looking the error log, I think it is an authentication based problem. But I am using the same email and password that I use for logging in to Bluemix. **By the way,** I tried it on Git command line. It is successfully cloned, commited, and pushed. And I do not understand why this problem happens in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the given steps-

1. Go to the git hub >> Settings >> Developer Setting >> Personal Access Token >> Click on "Generate New Token" >> Enter the some text on "Note" text field and select the 'repo'(all check box), 'admin:repo_hook'(select all check box), and 'delete repo' checkboxes >> Click on "Generate Token" button => After generate the token number then use this token number as password.
2. Now go to the eclipse and enter the username of git hub and enter the 'Token' number as a password field.

Answer (score 3):

Check in Git profile if you have made two factor authentication as ON. Because in that case when you connect from browser then it'll authenticate properly and connect but when you do it from eclipse it only checks normal credentials(username,password) and fails to authenticate.

Answer (score 3):

I wasted hours please follow the below steps

Go to github profile.
Click on settings
Settings->Developer settings->Personal access tokens->
Generate new token.

Provide Expiration depend on your requirememt.(See screenshot)

Copy the token.

Now go to eclipse git clone add Https git url.

**Enter username** as email id
**Password** must be your generated **TOKEN** just paste it.

Congrats You are done!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this from end-to-end and had no problems. Possibly it was transient? Can you try again, please?

Here are the steps I took to reproduce:

```
File/Import...
Select dialog
* Git/Projects from Git
* click next

Select Repository Source dialog
* Clone URI
* click next

Source Git Repository dialog
* from Settings page (e.g. https://hub.jazz.net/project/you/yourproject/settings/general)
* copy the Git URL e.g. https://hub.jazz.net/git/you/yourproject
(Host and Repository Path should populate)
* populate User and Password with your IBM ID
* click next

Branch Selection dialog
* (master should be selected)
* click next

Local Destination dialog
* select a local destination
* click next

Select a wizard to use for importing projects dialog
* (Import existing projects should be selected)
* click finish
```

et voila!

If the Git URL is incorrectly entered, then the Select Branch dialog will respond with the error dialog described in the original question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I am getting this error in "Branch Selection Dialog" step and it does not show any branches.

Comment: ah, another clue... so, I was able to recreate the problem by misspelling the project name in the Git URL. Can you please check that you are correctly specifying the Git URL? Again, see above for how to find that value in IDS.

Comment: Yes, I directly copied it from Bluemix page. It is working without error on Git Command Line, but not on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the exact same problem of : "incorrect URL, or incorrect passwrd and SSL not verified".
I googled that and was asked to change in the .git config file and update the parameter to: "sslVerify=false", but that didn't work.
After more searching I updated the git plugin for eclipse to the latest version and it worked. Please do check by updating if there are updates available to the git plugin, install them and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.

Select the option 'Clone Git Repository', the problem was solved when I pasted the URL as HTTP protocol, and changed the 'Connection Protocol' to Git:

Before: http://github.com/My_Account/My_Repository.git

After: git://github.com/My_Account/My_Repository.git

Then try to run.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Eclipse Mars has some issue with GIT plugin. I was using Eclipse Mars and facing the same issue. I installed Eclipse Oxygen and it worked without any issues. So before you dig further into it, just try with Eclipse Oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, initially I used the username and password , but later when I used username@gmail.com and then password , the error did not show up. Not sure if it will work for everyone though.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26839947)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26839947)

Comment: @NicoHaase: this post appears to be an answer. It may be a bit brief, and you may think it warrants a downvote, but it does contain answer detail.

Comment: @halfer currently, there is not a single downvote on this answer. But providing some more context could help a lot to understand **how** this solves the problem, as the OP wrote that he already used a mail adress

Comment: You've misunderstood me, @NicoHaase. I'm suggesting that a boilerplate review note of "If you have a new question" is not appropriate, because it is obviously not a question. We are agreed it could do with some improvement, which is why I suggested that a downvote is perhaps a better response. Whether it has downvotes already is immaterial.

Comment: @pczeus: the same feedback is for you (based on your boilerplate review note of "If you have a different question..."). This might not be a great answer, it may even be a wrong answer, but it is still an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using an old version of Eclipse. I downloaded and installed the latest version and it started working again.